# Ubuntu 14.04 not showing login info - motd

Tags: 14.04, login, sshd

I have a server ubuntu 14.04.03 setup inside a data-center and one on a virtual machine. Unfortunatelly the one in the data-center only shows this info after login:

```
ssh fx1
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.19.0-26-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/
No mail.
Last login: Wed Nov 18 09:07:08 2015 from 127.red-83-52-183.dynamicip.rima-tde.net
```

While the other one provides much more helpful info upon login:

```
ssh node1
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.19.0-30-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

  System information as of Tue Nov 17 17:22:48 CET 2015

  System load:  0.15              Users logged in:     0
  Usage of /:   78.7% of 8.59GB   IP address for eth0: 192.168.56.120
  Memory usage: 5%                IP address for eth1: 10.0.0.120
  Swap usage:   0%                IP address for eth2: 192.168.1.178
  Processes:    174               IP address for tun0: 10.7.0.1

  => /data/mysql is using 85.1% of 14.64GB

  Graph this data and manage this system at:
    https://landscape.canonical.com/

32 packages can be updated.
17 updates are security updates.

Last login: Tue Nov 17 17:22:48 2015 from 192.168.56.1
```

How can I change this? `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` looks about the same.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into manual pages for `sshd_config(5)`. There is option `PrintMotd`, which makes `sshd` print this message of the day.

But make sure the MOTD is available in the correct path `/etc/motd`, correctly updated if you want to have it dynamic and that you restart your ssh service after the changes.

Comment: /etc/ssh/sshd_config shows printMotd no on both servers and the file/dir /etc/motd is not present on neither of both. However the message apears on the server I have at home every time I log in.